# How to move the modifed .js file after MVC application moved to production

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I have a MVC web application and I have deployed it.

After that I have modified a .js file which alone needs to be moved to production. I did moved the .js file and it doesn't take the latest changes js file in production, instead it use only the previous one during the deployment.

My question is 
1. Is the .js files are also get complied along with the .dll files?
2. Is there a way to move the modified .js file alone to the production without moving the complied code?

Comment: *it doesn't get the latest js file in production* I assume that you want to say production site doesn't reflect the changes after update js file right?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't get the latest changes from the .js file

Comment: May its because of browser caching, please check to remove caching.

Comment: Do you mean clear the cache in client browser?

Comment: Yes, just CTR + Shift + Delete and clear cache data.

Comment: are you sure that .js files need not be complied with MVC application?

Comment: I'm very sure. Js file is client script, and compilation need to only server side code.

Comment: Any update here ?

Answer (score 0):

That may be because of client browser caching. please check to remove caching.
So, just <kbd>CTR</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and clear cached data.

> Is the .js files are also get complied along with the .dll files

No, always calls file will complied.

> Is there a way to move the modified .js

Simple way is to replace your latest js file with old js file

> production without moving the complied code?

No, need to deploy whole code all the times.

Moreover, you can go though a document: [Determining What Files Need to Be Deployed](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/determining-what-files-need-to-be-deployed-cs)

And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9322505